# Path Pattern Android intent-filter

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am using deep links in my android application.

I have web page that contains numbers on the start, so I need check it at pattern as here:

```
<intent-filter android:label="test_label">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="url.com" android:pathPattern="/[0-9]*,.*.html" />


            </intent-filter>
```

And my link:

```
link.com/245576,example-url-example.html
```

What is wrong?
It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

At first you limit your intent to http://url the path you have defined is invalid since it is no RegEx. The path can just contain a common prefix. You can check in the intent which full path was given.